# Is it possible to receive post data in angular?

Tags: angular

For ckeditor i want to upload files.
It uses an uploadUrl, for example '/uploadFile'.
Now i want to make an endpoint for this backend within angular that receives/processes the file. Is it possible to receive post data in angular?

Comment: in my understanding, angular is clientside so it cannot receive any requests

Comment: Thanks, so ckeditor way of dealing with upload makes a seperate backend server necessary.